# Best way to keep web application data sync with elasticsearh

Tags: python, mysql, django, elasticsearch

I'm developing a web application in Python with Django for scheduling medical services. The database using is Mysql.

The system has several complex searches. For good performance, I'm using elasticsearch. The idea is to index only searchable data. The document created in the ES is not exactly the same as modeling in the database, for example, the Patient entity has relationships in the DB that are mapped as attributes in the ES.

I am in doubt at what time to update the record in the ES when some relationship is updated.

I am currently updating the registry in ES whenever an object is created, changed or deleted in the DB. In the case of relationships, I need to fetch the parent entity to update the record.

Another strategy would be to do the full index periodically. The problem with this strategy is the delay between a change and it's available for search.

What would be the best strategy in this case?

Comment: There is no best strategy. Don't optimize prematurely. Do you experience any issues with the current strategy? If no, then don't bother :)